# Undefined Symbols for Architecture when Installing QT Statically

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I'm trying to deploy a C++ QT application currently for Mac, and will move onto Windows soon, but I'm currently having problems.

I've downloaded the QT source to compile statically. I first cd to the downloaded source directory, then run `./configure -static`, which runs fine, but does say `WARNING: Unable to find file .device.vars`, not sure if that's a problem or not. Then I try to run `make sub-src`, but it says `No rule to make target 'sub-src'. Stop.`, so I try plain old `make` instead, which runs for a while, then gives me the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()", referenced from:
      qBadAlloc() in libQt5Core_debug.a(qglobal.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [qmleasing] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sub-qmleasing-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-tools-make_first] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Error 2
```

Googling yields no results (from what I can see) :( How can I successfully statically build QT so I can deploy my application, or if statically building is no longer an option, how else can I deploy my app?

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT: Probably should add that I'm running OSX 10.8.3, 64 bit, QT dynamically installed under /Applications/QT, attempting to build this in a folder on my desktop.

Comment: Just plain ./configure -static? I guess you should add more platform, at least -no-webkit, as Webkit can't be build static. Check also for clang compiler... http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/platform-details.html [Remind that static build requires a commercial license http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352896/qt-commercial-licenses/7698580#7698580]